# Flask pagination without query strings

Tags: python, flask, pagination

I am working on a "tag" system similar to how a wordpress blog has tags.

I have managed to have a route working nicely with pagination using flask-pagination library, however the urls have query strings. I would like instead of having urls like domain.com/tag.html?page=2 to instead have urls like domain.com/tag-2.html

Any help would be much appreciated. This is my current route:

```
def tags_main():
model = compile_page.Tags(db)
page = request.args.get('page', default=0, type=int)
limit = 15
offset = page * limit - limit
total_pages = model.get_all_tagged()
tagged_pages = model.get_all_tags(limit=limit, offset=page * limit)
print(tagged_pages)
pagination = Pagination(page=page, per_page=limit, total=total_pages, css_framework='bulma',
                        tagged_pages=tagged_pages)
posts_data = {
    'tagged_pages': tagged_pages,
    'pagination': f"/tag.html?page=",
    'present_page': page,
}
return render_template('ssr_templates/tag.html', posts_data=posts_data, pagination=pagination)
```

Thanks in advance for any help or tips to set me on the right path.

Answer (score 0):

You can have dynamic pages like that:

```
@app.route('/tag-<int:page>')
def tag(page: int):
    return f"doing stuff with {page}"
```

Comment: Thank you @eagr, its a really nice idea I have not considered. I will play around with this a little bit. I'm quite the novice with python and flask, I will update here with my results.

Comment: Seems to be a really good way to do this, what Im struggling with now is how to pass the rest of the data into the second route ('/tag-<int:page>) so that it displays the correct data for the page

Comment: What is the rest of that data that you want to pass to the route? You have the desired page so you can fetch the relevant items with pagination.

Comment: Im sure this is really silly what I am trying to do (such a novice), but Ive tried to pass the data like this:

@app.route('/tag-<int:page>.html')
def tag(page: int, pagination, posts_data):
    pagination = pagination
    posts_data = posts_data
    return f"doing stuff with {page} and {pagination} and {posts_data}"

but of course I am receiving a 500 error on the pages like that. Id like to be able to pass the data that will belong on the current page, as well as the current place for "active" page in the pagination.

Comment: The post request data is available at flask.request.json (make sure to send from client with json content-type)

Comment: Ah ok, thanks again! Ill play around with it.